# How to Create Conda Environment in AWS Lambda at Run Time?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, anaconda, conda

I am using an AWS lambda as part of my CI/CD pipeline. The lambda checks out some code using the provided git url and commit hash in the event. Then, it goes into the source code and does a `conda env create -f env.yml`, and then runs a python file `python flow.py run`. Unfortunately, installing and activating a conda environment is proving to be problematic as conda creates cache files in the `/home/sbx_user` directory, and AWS Lambda doesn't have option to write to any direction except `/tmp`. I get the following error as an example:

```
Creating Conda environment 'torch_model'...
CondaError: Cannot write to condarc file at /home/sbx_user1051/.condarc
Caused by FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
CondaError: Cannot write to condarc file at /home/sbx_user1051/.condarc
Caused by FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
CondaError: Error encountered while attempting to create cache directory.
Directory: /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/conda/notices
Exception: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
```

One thing I've also tried is setting `HOME` as `/tmp` in hopes that the conda environment and cache files would be installed in the `tmp` folder, which the Lambda does have write access to. But this attempt was unsuccessful as well and returned the following error:

```
environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
```

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you describe looks very much like a `CodeBuild` job. Are you sure you have to do this in Lambda?

Comment: Yes I think so because our security posture is annoyingly complicated. We are already using Jenkins, and Jenkins is invoking the Lambda